# VueJS component called 2 times in nested route using Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, nested-routes

I have a Laravel App and I'm trying to add a vuejs form. The form has 3 differents steps so I want to use [vuejs nested routes](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html).

**Problem is the parent component is called 2 times.**

`OnboardingForm.vue` : parent view, calling child components.

```
<template>
    <div class="steps-container">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="step-progress">
            Current step x {{ current_step }}
            </div>

            <router-view v-on:setStep="setStep"></router-view>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            current_step: null
        }
    },
    methods: {
        setStep(step) {
            this.current_step = step;
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

The router view is working fine but the `<div class="steps-container">` is rendered 2 times :

```
<div class="steps-container">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="step-progress">
      Current step
    </div>
    <div class="steps-container">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="step-progress">
          Current step from-component-1
        </div>
        <!-- Then the child component is successfully rendered -->
        <div class="content-of-component">Component 1</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

#### Associated files

Laravel route calling Controller `web.php`

```
Route::get('/onboarding/{any?}', [App\Http\Controllers\FormController::class, 'onboarding']);
```

*Note this controller is only returning the blade file `view('onboarding')`. Also `onboarding.blade.php` is calling my main component `<OnboardingForm>`*

VueJS Routes

```
const router = new VueRouter({
mode: 'history',
routes: [
    {
        path: '/onboarding',
        component: OnboardingForm,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'step1',
                component: Component1
            },
            {
                path: 'step2',
                component: Component2
            }
        ]
    },
],
});
```

I am maybe wrong using both VueJS and Laravel routing system together.

Comment: Have you researched about "maybe (being) wrong using both VueJS and Laravel routing system together"?

Comment: can u put your `setStep` function?

Comment: @KamleshPaul Thank you for your answer. I put the complete OnboardingForm.vue, although the `setStep` method doesn't seems to be part of the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is coming from the blade file : I was directly calling the parent component `<onboarding-form>` instead of the `<router-view>`.

So the component was loaded once, then the route system tried to load it again.

`mybladefile.php`

```
<div class="container" id="steps">
    <onboarding-form></onboarding-form>
</div>
```

become

```
<div class="container" id="steps">
    <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```